# What's the best inline function for Jquery Plus Minus buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm very bad in Jquery :-(
I have a form with different rows of items and each row has a `[-] [#] [+]`.
By clicking on + or - both text field and hidden should change, but I don't know how to figure it out.

[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
 <input type='button' value='-' onclick="" />
 <input type='text' id="t1" name='quantity' value='1' />
 <input type='button' value='+' onclick="" />
 <input type="hidden" id="qty" value="0" />
</form>
```

Any kind help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Aside from the fact your question is too broad, please don't use inline event handlers. It's not 1997 any more.

Comment: This is not a `Please  write code for me` platform. First try at your end and then come with your issue. [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work for the give example, with only one input - however you may want to alter the function, and ID's of the elements so you can use the same function to alter any input.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#plus,#minus').on('click',handlePlusMinus);     
});
 
function handlePlusMinus(event){
 var val = parseInt($('#t1').val()) + parseInt($(this).data("val"));
 $('#t1').val(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
 <input type='button' id='minus' value='-' data-val='-1' />
 <input type='text' id="t1" name='quantity' value='1' />
 <input type='button' id='plus' value='+' data-val='1'/>
</form>
```